# Javascript Forms Select Selectedindex

Tags: javascript, forms, select, selectedindex

Having problems with the following - Not working as expected, getting JS doc errors as well.

[JSFiddle Nota Worka.](http://jsfiddle.net/aglasser/egjF4/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/egjF4/6/

and change the if line to:

```
if (document.forms['myform'].selectbox1.selectedIndex == 2)
```

you need the `==` to check values

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments below here is the jQuery for the same thing:

```
$(function(){
    $('#selectbox1').change(function(){
        if(this.selectedIndex == 2){
            $('#input1, #input2, #asterisk').css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('#input2').addClass('required');
        }
        else {
            $('input, #asterisk').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $('#input2').removeClass('required');
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Without seeming to ask for a ton, is doing this in Jquery better practice? I'm so unfamiliar with JScript and 5 min ago read that doing all this using Jquery is better for X-browser issues. Is Jquery better than JS? Or some flavor of JS? And if so, is it coded WAY differently.  (this worked perfectly by the way..ur fiddle)

Comment: @adg, #1 accept an answer #2, jQuery is library of js, ill show in a fiddle in a minute

Comment: All of you guys were right, but Neal was kind enough to show me this JQuery stuff. I think I like JQuery better. Is there good reference online to it? Or will I google it and find that billions exist. :) Jeez.

Comment: Fantastic. Ya. Looking at it now. Wowza. I've seen it before but I never put it together. I thought it was some obscure language. -- Yes, I'm "the new guy in town".

Comment: @adg also you can get lots o help on jquery by looking at their forums and on stack

Comment: Ya, this is nice. It's got everything here. Can't thank you enough. Saved me hours. I've been working on this visible/hide thing for 5 days. No kidding. :)

Comment: haha yes, jQuery even has cool animations like `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` in the jQueryUI section, and many more ^_^

Comment: Yessiree. This is very happening. I've been sifting thru all the Jquery stuff for the last 4 hours. Loving it.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do this, http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/egjF4/10/

```
var form = document.getElementById('myform');
if (form.selectbox1.selectedIndex == 2)
```

this way you're caching the form in case you want to reference it later, preventing another element lookup and speeding up your code.

Comment: All of you guys were correct, except that choosing options 1 and 3 would also make the hidden elements appear.

Comment: if you check my fiddle, the elements are hidden when 1 and 3 are selected and shown only when 2 is selected

Comment: Yes, I tried to update my comment. I was looking at another fiddle. Probably my own :) No, yours was perfect :) Thanks so much. --

Answer (score 0):

I believe jsfiddle runs in it's own little protective XPC bubble, so showhidebtime will not be seen as defined via an inline javascript call. Best practice is to always add events in the javascript file, not inline with the elements.

Also you need to change your form to show `name="myform"` in order for `document.myform` to work.

Try this **fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/qb6fw/

Comment: When you say inline (sorry, I'm, uh, "the new guy"), do you mean calling showhidebtime() within the <select> html element?

Comment: Also, when I select option 1 or 3 both elements leave the hidden state.

Comment: inline javascript = `javascript:` on elements, just like how you describe "inline" css via `<div style="blah">`